# FOSUserBundle discriminator mapping registration

Tags: php, symfony, fosuserbundle, discriminator

I have a class **User** and two children-classes **Prestataire** and **Membre**.
I've made a mapping discrimination.

Class User.php

```
namespace Annuaire\AnnuaireBundle\Entity;

use FOS\UserBundle\Model\User as BaseUser;
use DateTime;
use Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection;
use \Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;



/**
 * @ORM\Table()
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="UserRepository")
 * @ORM\InheritanceType("SINGLE_TABLE")
 * @ORM\DiscriminatorColumn(name="type_user", type="string")
 * @ORM\DiscriminatorMap({"admin" = "User", "membre" = "Membre", "prestataire" = "Prestataire"})
 */
class User extends BaseUser
{
    const Type_USER = 'admin';
    const Type_PRESTATAIRE = 'prestataire';
    const Type_MEMBRE = 'membre';


    public function __construct() {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->typeUser = User::Type_USER;
        $this->dateInscr = new DateTime();
        $this->confInscr = false;  
        $this->banni = false;
        $this->nmbEssais = null;  
        $this->images = new ArrayCollection();
    }

....

    function getTypeuser() {
        return $this->typeUser;
    }

    function setTypeuser($typeUser) {
        $this->typeUser = $typeUser;
    }
```

Class Prestataire.php

```
namespace Annuaire\AnnuaireBundle\Entity;
use Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="Annuaire\AnnuaireBundle\Entity\PrestataireReposito     ry")
 */
class Prestataire extends User
{
    public function __construct() {
        $this->typeUser = User::Type_PRESTATAIRE;    
        $this->stages = new ArrayCollection();  
        $this->promos = new ArrayCollection();  
        $this->categories = new ArrayCollection();
        $this->favorites = new ArrayCollection();
        parent::__construct();
    }
```

Class Membre.php

```
namespace Annuaire\AnnuaireBundle\Entity;
use Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 * @ORM\Entity
 */
class Membre extends User
{

    public function __construct() {
        $this->typeUser = User::Type_MEMBRE;       

        $this->notes = new ArrayCollection();    
        $this->favorites = new ArrayCollection();    
        parent::__construct();
    }
```

When user would log-on he choose one of two user's types. So the parameter of type is sended by URL *register/prestataire* or *register/membre*.
And I don't know how I can set a Type in the DataBase by FOSUserBundle.